# jQuery POST/GET in same function

Tags: jquery

with this function I send data from form to external file:

```
function save() {
  var data = $('#formId').serialize();
  var url = 'test.php';
  $.post(url, data, function (response) {
    alert("GOOD");
  });
}
```

In test.php I save values witch I take with $_POST, after inserting values now I make another query to db which return me JSON. I want to take this json data and push it back to same jQuery function from beginning and show it in div with id="reza"

I try to add `$.get` JSON to response function and now script is:

```
function save() {
  var data = $('#formId').serialize();
  var url = 'test1.php';
  $.post(url, data, function (response) {
    //----------this is new part------
    $.getJSON("test.php", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        $("#reza").append(field.name);
      });    
    });
  });
}
```

Please help me to catch response data.

Comment: can you explain which part doesn't work?
Is there any `result` and `response` ?

Comment: In response function if I retreive json from different php it's ok, but when I want to take json data from same php file which I use for POST it doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any errors in the dev tools?

Comment: No I mean errors not the code. You can check the console F12 in your Browser (Chrome or Firefox)

Comment: I made some progress, I change code to this: function save(){ var data = $('#formId').serialize(); var url = 'test.php; $.post(url, data, function (response) { $.getJSON(response, function(result){ $.each(result, function(i, field){ $("#reza").append(field.name); }); }); }); } Now in error console i got error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", but in inspector I can see returned JSON, but I can't load it..

Comment: Can you update your code inside the question, please.

Comment: and you are using `test1.php` for `post` but you wrote `test.php` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to all who give me tips for my first question on stackoverflow, I solved problem, solution is:

```
function save() {
    var data = $('#formId').serialize();
    var url = 'test1.php';
    $.post(url, data, function (response) {
        $.each(response, function(i, field) {
            $("#reza").append(field.name);
        });    
    });
}
```

I have wrong approach at beginning, I try to get json, but I don't need that. So in my solution I take returned data from function which give me response (already in json) and go trough loop to display it. Hope this will help someone, cheers!